# JOGL: some GL constants can not be resolved

Tags: image, textures, jogl

i've written a java program with JOGL included.
Everything worked fine, until i wanted to render an image (jpg,gif,png) with a texture.
i found following code snippet:

```
import javax.media.opengl.*;
...
GL2 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL2();

gl.glTexParameteri(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL.GL_CLAMP);
gl.glTexParameteri(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL.GL_CLAMP);
gl.glTexParameteri(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL.GL_LINEAR);
gl.glTexParameteri(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL.GL_LINEAR);
gl.glTexEnvf(GL.GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL.GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL.GL_REPLACE);
gl.glTexImage2D(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL.GL_RGBA, w, h, 0, GL.GL_RGBA, GL.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, bb);

int left = 100;
int top = 100;
gl.glEnable(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
gl.glBindTexture(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 13);
gl.glBegin(GL.GL_POLYGON);
...
```

the problem is that Eclipse can't resolve `GL.GL_CLAMP`, `GL.GL_TEXTURE_ENV`, `GL.GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE` and `GL.GL_POLYGON`.
as an alternative for `GL.GL_CLAMP` there is just `GL.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE`.
i can't even find `GL.GL_QUAD`, just `GL.GL_TRIANGLE`.
what is wrong?
do i missed an import?
other GL constants can be resolved.

regards,
peter

Comment: solved it by using GL2 instead of GL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proper way in JOGL2 is `GL2.GL_CLAMP` (not `GL.GL_CLAMP`). [API Docs](https://jogamp.org/deployment/v2.1.5/javadoc/jogl/javadoc/javax/media/opengl/GL2.html#GL_CLAMP)